# Can't change two main Bootstrap columns altogether (col-sm-4 & col-sm-8)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, calculated-columns

I have two main columns in a bootstrap website. The first is the sidebar column and the second is the main content column. In Desktop they appear fine but in Mobile the sidebar doesn't go under the main-content area.

You could see a live example for this [in one of the regular nodes of my site](http://www.beniaharon.co.il/about-beniaharon), just view the site in mobile mode, browse downwards a bit, and you will see this.

Please help,

Comment: Can you tell me what is the ultimate result you want with Bootstrap?

Comment: That the sidebar column area will be smaller and the main-content column area will be larger and it will appear fine in both desktop and mobile --- In mobile screens the sidebar should be under the main content and not left to it.

Comment: I think you have to change the column-width more appropriately. E.g.: `col-sm-7 col-lg-8` on `#primary` and `col-sm-5 col-lg-4` on `#sidebar`.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your answer --- What should be changed or added in Style.css? I might understand you better after I'll edit the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Bootstrap 3 grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
>
> Each tier of classes scales up, meaning if you plan on setting the same widths for xs and sm, you only need to specify xs.
>   http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Container width  None (auto) 750px       970px       1170px  
> Class prefix     .col-xs-    .col-sm-   .col-md-     .col-lg-
> ```
>
> http://getbootstrap.com/css/

### To address your issue

> In Desktop they appear fine but in Mobile the sidebar doesn't go under the main-content area.

You should not modify the bootstrap grid, but you can use the existing bootstrap grid to achieve what you want.

#### For example

Remove any CSS which modifies the grid and change this...

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-sm-8">
...
</div>
...
<aside id="sidebar" class="col-sm-4" role="complementary">
...
</aside>
```

To...

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
...
</div>
...
<aside id="sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" role="complementary">
...
</aside>
```

This tells the browser

> If the viewport is less than 750px wide, the columns should take the entire width, else they should be displayed side by side

### Changing column widths

> #### Grid system
>
> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.

When you have define the columns using the prefixes, `col-xs-` `col-sm-` `col-md-` and `col-lg-`, the numbers following the prefix must add up to 12 for each row.

#### Four examples

If you would like two columns of the same width you would use

```
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
6 + 6 = 12
```

If you would like three columns of the same width you would use

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
4 + 4 + 4 = 12
```

If you would like two columns where one column is twice the size of the first you would use

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-8"></div>
4 + 8 = 12
```

If you would like two columns where one column is three times the size of the other you would use

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-9"></div>
3 + 9 = 12
```

And so on and so forth

Comment: small update, found another problem so I restored the original page.tpl.php I changed the Primary to <?php if($page['sidebar_first']) { $primary_col = 9; } else { $primary_col = 12; } ?> ------i.e changed the first col from 8 to 9. And I've also changed <aside id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3" role="complementary"> ------i.e changed col-sm-4 to col-sm-3.

Answer (score 0):

Remove you CSS changes and Use `col-lg-9` on primary and `col-lg-3` on sidebar instead of current code.

**Primary**

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-lg-9">
```

**Sidebar**

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="col-lg-3" role="complementary">
```

Comment: What do you mean to use them? Should I delete what I already changed in Style.css and add something else? Please elaborate, Thank you dearly (!!!)

Comment: Just remove your custom CSS and use these classes instead of what you were having initially.